# Install a 240 volt mini-split condenser with a plug?

Tags: 240v, cord-and-plug

Is it possible to have a 240 volt mini-split condenser installed with an appropriate plug instead of a dedicated electrical line? Given that the circuit(s) used will be properly allotted for the unit. We are rebuilding our hurricane damaged house section-by-section, so the spot where the AC will be installed will be temporary. Not a huge problem. Just seems like it might be more convenient. Thanks.

Comment: Voltages have been 120/240 in the U.S. for about 70 years, FYI.

Comment: I would think the other way!   If code required a socket, you might want to hardwire in your temporary location to avoid installing a temporary socket.   But since code requires hard wiring, what convenience are you gaining by installing a temporary socket?  Doesn't the A/C unit include entry, strain relief, and connectors for your supply cable, so that you must provide nothing, whereas with a socket you'll need to supply a box, socket, plug, cord, and to mount it all on the wall ... only to take it all down again later?

Answer (score 5):

Electrically it would function, but NEC only allows receptacle attachment for single room AC units, and gives specific conditions. The intent of the wording expects a through-the-wall installation so it may be difficult meet the conditions:

> 440.63...(1) the manual controls on the room air conditioner are located within 6 ft. of the floor, or (2)  an approved manually operable disconnecting means is installed in a readily accessible location within sight from the room
> air conditioner.

It might be a bit convoluted to convince an inspector that the indoor portion complies with the requirement.

And the changes in the 2020 NEC might make that a little more complicated.

> 210.8(A) Dwelling Units. All 125-volt **through 250-volt** receptacles installed in the locations specified in 210.8(A)(1) through (A)⁠(11)
> and supplied by single-phase branch circuits rated 150 volts or less
> to ground shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for
> personnel...
>
> (3) Outdoors...

So if you are in a jurisdiction using the 2020 NEC you would be required to use a GFCI breaker. The breaker might have inrush issues, and it would probably be cheaper to just go ahead and buy the disconnect and whip that you will eventually need anyway since when hard wired ground fault protection isn't required.

Comment: Also make sure gfci breaker is correctly hp rated, the receptacle is hp rated,  receptacle amperage rating is 115% and wire is 125%.

Comment: I conceptually divide what people do in electrical wiring into 3 categories:
1)  Not safe, not code legal
2) Safe, but not code legal
3) Safe and code legal

I think you are in #2. Like NoSparksPlease said, a whip would probably be less expensive than a 240v plug and outlet and the associated type S cable needed to go to the outdoor unit.  That stuff can be pricey.  The whip would be code legal and probably cheaper.

Comment: So, in reality, installing a plugged system is the more complicated route. Makes sense. Thanks a ton for the info.

Answer (score 4):

So your plan is to move either the condenser or evaporator of your split system? That will result in needing to redo part of the refrigeration lines which is far from a trivial task.

Doing a bit of electrical to disconnect the old location and reconnect at the new one is much easier in comparison to redoing part of your refrigeration lines.

With a bit of planning you can reuse the temporary circuit. So that's the least of your troubles.

Comment: This is a good point.  It might be cheaper to buy, temporarily use, and sell a small window A/C than to move a mini split!

Comment: Jay - we are using portable ACs in our temp living spaces, but can't have that kind of noise in our office space as we have a lot of phone calls and video meetings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Be sure it is appropriate for the environment it is in. I would think it would much easier and cost less to wire it directly. You could mount the disconnect temporarily and leave enough wire on the feed so when you do the permanent install you have everything already there, just needing a bit of work.